# Weird Characters encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, special-characters, carrierwave

I have a weird behaviour in my params whichare passed as utf-8 but the special characters are not well managed.
Instead of 1 special character, I have 2 characters: the normal letter + the accent.

```
Parameters: {"name"=>"Mylène.png", "_cardbiz_session"=>"be1d5b7a2f27c7c4979ac4c16fe8fc82", "authenticity_token"=>"9vmJ02DjgKYCpoBNUcWwUlpxDXA8ddcoALHXyT6wrnM=", "asset"=>{"file"=># < ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f94d38d37d0 @original_filename="Mylène.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"asset[file]\"; filename=\"Myle\xCC\x80ne.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n", @tempfile=# < File:/var/folders/q5/yvy_v9bn5wl_s5ccy_35qsmw0000gn/T/RackMultipart20130805-51100-1eh07dp > >}, "id"=>"copie-de-sm"}
```

I log this:

- logger.debug file_name
- logger.debug file_name.chars.map(&:to_s).inspect

Each time, same result:

- Mylène
- ["M", "y", "l", "e", "̀", "n", "e"]

As i try to use the filename as a matcher with already existing names properly encoded utf-8, you see my problem ;)

- Encodings are utf-8 everywhere.
- working under ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.14.
- Added #encoding: utf-8 in top of any file involved.

I anyone as an idea,  take it !

I also published an Issue here : https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1185 but not sure if its a carrierwave issue or me missing something...

Comment: Sounds like a problem with [Unicode equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) Did you try a  Unicode normalization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be linked to MACOSX.

https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4407424 explains it and refers to https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7267 for more details and discution.

MACOSX decomposing special characters into **utf8-mac** instead of **utf-8**...

While you can't know the encoding of a file name, just presupose it.

Thanks to our Linux guy where it works properly. ;)

```
file_name.encode!('utf-8', 'utf-8-mac').chars.map(&:to_s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have a *[Combining character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character)* and a problem with [Unicode equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence)

When I check the codepoints with:

```
#encoding: utf-8
Parameters =  {"name"=>"Mylène.png",}

p Parameters['name'].codepoints.to_a
```

I get `Myl\u00E8ne.png`, but I think that's a conversion problem when I copy the text. It would be helpfull, if you can provide a file with the raw data.

I expect you have a [combining grave accent](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/300/index.htm) and a `e`

The solution would be a Unicode normalization. (Sorry, I don't know how to do it with ruby. Perhaps somebody else has an answer for it).

---

You found your problem, so this is not needed any longer for you.

But in meantime I found a mechanism to normalize Unicode strings:

```
#encoding: utf-8
text = "Myl\u00E8ne.png" #"Mylène.png"
text2 = "Myle\u0300ne.png" #"Mylène.png"

puts text   #Mylène.png
puts text2  #Mylène.png

p text == text2 #false

#http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Multibyte/Unicode/normalize
require 'active_support'
p text                                                                   #"Myl\u00E8ne.png"
p ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Unicode.normalize(text, :d) #"Myle\u0300ne.png"

p text2                                                                   #"Myle\u0300ne.png"
p ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Unicode.normalize(text2, :c)#"Myl\u00E8ne.png"
```

Maybe there is an easier way, but up to now I found none.

Comment: Thanks for the leading clue ! :) Found it's MACOSX fault which use utf-8-mac encoding for file system naming...