# The length of a string with umlauts coming from the filesystem

Tags: ruby, string, utf-8, diacritics

**Update** Rephrased my question:

I have  small script which creates a summary for each directory in a given folder:

```
def processDir(dir)
  title = "Project #{dir}"
<<EOF
#{title}
#{'-' * title.length}
...    


EOF
end
```

So now with folders that contain umlauts the length of the title does not match so I end up with an extra dash in some cases:

```
phone
-----

Propadeutikum
-------------

Propädeutikum
--------------
             ^ extra dash!
```

So I am looking for a way to calculate the exact length of my string.

**Update:**: This is really weird, depending on where I copy it from I get differnt results in my console.

```
1.9.3-p448 :012 > "Propädeutikum".length
 => 13 
1.9.3-p448 :013 > "Propädeutikum".length
 => 14
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby string does supprot only **ASCII** chracters till now. So you can use the gem - [`unicode`](http://rubygems.org/gems/unicode) for this, when you will be having **non-ascii charcaters**. Look here also - [`width`](http://www.yoshidam.net/unicode.txt) .

```
require "unicode"

s1 = "Propädeutikum"
s2 = "Propadeutikum"
Unicode::width(s1) # => 13
Unicode::width(s2) # => 13
```

Read this post [`Re: how to capitalize nonascii characters ?`](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4422411#1135623)

> Hi,
>
> Yes, use unicode gem for now.  String operations on non ASCII
>   characters are one of the topics for upcoming Ruby 2.2.
>
> ```
>          matz.
> ```

Comment: @Besi It should, wait till *2.2* as *matz* said. :-)

Comment: @ArupRakshit +1 for the information, I think you should be running in the SO elections :) you do alot for the ruby tag on SO, thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 3):

In unicode some characters, such as `ä`, can be represented in two ways. They can be a single codepoint, such as U+00E4 in the case of `ä`, or they can be formed from a “base” character immediately followed by a [combining character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) such as `a` followed by U+0308 (COMBINING DIAERESIS). In the latter case, the combined character consists of two code points, and Ruby’s `String#length` method only returns the total number of code points so you can get differing values for the lengths of what appear to be the same strings.

```ruby
s1 = "ä"        # single codepoint
s2 = "a"        # 'base' letter
s3 = "a\u0308"  # base letter + combining character

[s1, s2, s3].each do |s|
  puts "Letter:     #{s}"
  puts "Bytes:      #{s.bytes}"
  puts "Codepoints: #{s.codepoints}"
  puts "Length:     #{s.length}"
  puts
end
```

Output:

```
Letter:     ä
Bytes:      [195, 164]
Codepoints: [228]
Length:     1

Letter:     a
Bytes:      [97]
Codepoints: [97]
Length:     1

Letter:     ä
Bytes:      [97, 204, 136]
Codepoints: [97, 776]
Length:     2
```

(The `bytes` is the UTF-8 encoding of the characters. In UTF-8 some characters are encoded as multiple bytes – this is a separate issue from the combining characters.)

Ruby itself doesn’t (currently) have very much support for dealing with unicode issues like this, so you need to use an external library such as [UnicodeUtils](https://github.com/lang/unicode_utils). The idea of `length` can become pretty unclear when talking about different languages (what counts as a ‘single character’. You could use the `display_width` method, which will probably give what you want for latin scripts. Another possibility is to use a [*normalized form*](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/), which makes sure all the characters are represented the same way, either all decomposed into conbining characters, or all (that have them available) using the single character:

```ruby
require 'unicode_utils'

combined = "a\u0308"
single = "ä"

# nfc - normalized form composed - use a single code point if possible
puts UnicodeUtils.nfc(combined).length # => 1
puts UnicodeUtils.nfc(single).length   # => 1

# nfd - normalized form decomposed - always use combining characters
puts UnicodeUtils.nfd(combined).length # => 2
puts UnicodeUtils.nfd(single).length   # => 2
```

Comment: Ok this is very interesting. Actually on my Keyboard I can press the `¨` key and then the `a` to get `ä` this. I am not sure if this results in a different character but it is the same concept.

Comment: @Besi You’re right, it’s the same sort of idea, but separate from the actual characters used. On my machine (a Mac) I can press `alt + u` followed by `a` to get `ä`, but the result is the single codepoint version.

Comment: @Besi looking at your edited question, the `display_width` (or just `width` from the `unicode` gem) is probably what you’re after in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Matt, but may be slightly more efficient.

```
"Propädeutikum".each_char.size
# => 13

t = Time.now
500000.times{
"Propädeutikum".each_char.size
}
puts Time.now - t
# => 0.364056992

t = Time.now
500000.times{
"Propädeutikum".chars.count
}
puts Time.now - t
# => 1.462392185
```

Comment: Same problem as with Matt's version.

Comment: @Besi It is your problem, not ours.

Comment: OK +1 for your time statistic (even though this is not a problem in my case, but useful to know). I get the strings from filenames so it is probably something related to the filesystem. And of course it is my problem, hence I am the one to ask the question :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a problem with Unicode equivalence and composed characters?

See the following example. Both texts look similar, but are encoded in different ways:

```
#encoding: utf-8
text = "Myl\u00E8ne.png" #"Mylène.png"
text2 = "Myle\u0300ne.png" #"Mylène.png"

puts text   #Mylène.png
puts text2  #Mylène.png

puts text.size   #10
puts text2.size  #11

puts text.chars.count #10
puts text2.chars.count #11
```

Some more details in [my answer for Weird Characters encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18077640/676874).

You can check it, if you compare the codepoints of your texts with `text.codepoints.to_a`.
In my example I get:

```
p text.codepoints.to_a   #[77, 121, 108, 232, 110, 101, 46, 112, 110, 103]
p text2.codepoints.to_a  #[77, 121, 108, 101, 768, 110, 101, 46, 112, 110, 103]
```

Comment: I guess you are right. `Unicode::width(string)` did fix the problem now.